# How can I easily hook into the maven error reporting infrastructure

Tags: maven-2, maven, vbscript, jenkins, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a maven2 project where I am manually executing some testing in the integration-test phase using the exec plugin to call a vbscript (it's Windows specific testing).  This is automated by Jenkins.  I'd like to hook the results of these tests into the error reporting infrastructure (surefire/failsafe), and possibly even provide some details on the test failures before failing the build in the post-integration-test phase (preferably through the standard failsafe mechanism).  Can I create my own test results file somehow?  Are there any details on the format?  Is there a better way?

Clarification, I'm after the following things:

1. Ability to add tests to the infrastructure so Jenkins will see the number of tests run manually.
2. Ability to mark specific tests as pass or fail and have the build marked as "unstable" under jenkins appropriately.
3. I do not want immediate failure of the build when the test fails (this leaves the application running).  I want to either mark it only as "unstable" or mark it as failed in the "verify" phase.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to encapsulate your test in a custom mojo which could leverage the built in logging mechanism.  Then you could just use javas runtime exec to execute your vb, gather your results, and print them to the log.  Something like this perhaps:

```
/**
 * Goal which generates.
 * 
 * @goal vbtest
 * 
 * @phase test
 */
public class VbTestMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    /**
     * @parameter expression="${project}"
     */
    private MavenProject project;

    /**
     * The directory for exploded something or other.
     * 
     * @parameter default-value="${vbtest.scriptFile}"
     * @required
     * @readonly
     */
    private String vbScriptFile;


    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        getLog().info( "Running VB Test " + vbScriptFile.getName() );

        // execute your vb script here and log whatever...
    }
}
```

Put this in its own project, then include in your pom thusly:

```
...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>test-vb</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>vbtest</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <scriptFile>${project.basedir}/vbtests/vbtest.vb</scriptFile>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
...
```

This is clearly not the complete solution, but may give you a good starting point.

Comment: I'm not wanting to just log the results.  I can do that already.  I'm after how do I cause the build to be marked at unstable (I think I can fail the build by returning an error from the vbscript).

Comment: @Jared, missed that part, anyway, if you want your build to fail due to that test failure: _org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException if an expected problem (such as a compilation failure) occurs. Throwing this exception causes a "BUILD FAILURE" message to be displayed._